# Crystal Report Table Cannot Be Found Error

Tags: crystal-reports

All.

I using SAP Crystal Reports for Enterprise 4 and have created a custom report. When generating the report via the application (Syteline ERP) I get the below error.

Crystal Experienced an exception while executing [ExecuteReport]; The table Rpt_TestSp;1 could not be found.

There are many custom reports, that all run fine, which use the same data connection that I've chosen when building this report. (SQL Server ODBC using the sa account as auth)

The ODBC connects without issue. I can choose my Stored Procedure and see all of the relevant columns and I can also see the data in Crystal on the Page Designer.

Can anyone offer some advise on how to troubleshoot this?

I've already ran SQL Profiler and it's not even getting to the EXEC Rpt_TestSp;1. I believe it's failing in Crystal first.

Comment: Have you tried `update database` using the `set datasource location` in crystal reports

Comment: Yes, I've tried that multiple times, as well as refreshing the data source. I've even created multiple ODBC's in both 64 and 32 ODBC Manager, one using SQL Auth with sa and one using Windows Auth with the Domain Admin, but neither of those have worked either. I don't understand how Crystal can see the datasource, I can see the data in the Crystal preview (I can even export the .pdf document directly from Crystal), but it fails at runtime.

Comment: Dev system is saperate to run time system? In that case check connections in run time environment

Comment: I've 'almost' solved this. I removed all data other than text objects from the report and it now runs. It now is repeatable by adding any one of my columns from my stored procedure into the body. There are no formula's, groups or any other of these types.